# PHP nested operator in array. Is it a bad practice?

Tags: php, arrays, coding-style

This is the example:

```
$call['args'][ count( $call['args'] ) - 1 ]
```

Operator **count** in array element (PHP).
Is it a bad practice or just normal codestyle?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a bad practice as the **count** function returns the value instead of changing the variable provided as parameter.

So we can use count function directly instead of saving the count in separate variable. and as it returns only integer values we can do mathematical operations directly.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative and exact equivalent would be:

```
$index = count($call['args']) - 1;
$call['args'][$index];
```

It's perfectly possible to inline this operation instead of using a variable, the only difference arguably is readability. If it's readable and comprehensible enough when inlined, there's no reason to do it any other way. Only if the inlined operation is too complex to easily read does it help to introduce a helper variable (or obviously if you need the variable again later).